# In this example, how does the base template class determine the second concrete type?

Tags: c++, class, templates

```
    template<typename ConcreteOccGridMap>
    class OccGridMapUtilConfig
      : public OccGridMapUtil<ConcreteOccGridMap, GridMapCacheMethod>
    {
    public:

      OccGridMapUtilConfig(ConcreteOccGridMap* gridMap = 0)
        : OccGridMapUtil<ConcreteOccGridMap, GridMapCacheMethod>(gridMap)
      {}
    };

    }


    template<typename ConcreteOccGridMap, typename ConcreteCacheMethod>
    class OccGridMapUtil
    {
    public:

      OccGridMapUtil(const ConcreteOccGridMap* gridMap)
        : concreteGridMap(gridMap)
        , size(0)
      {
        mapObstacleThreshold = gridMap->getObstacleThreshold();
        cacheMethod.setMapSize(gridMap->getMapDimensions());
      }

      ~OccGridMapUtil()
      {}


       Eigen::Vector4f intensities;

       ConcreteCacheMethod cacheMethod;

       const ConcreteOccGridMap* concreteGridMap;

       std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> samplePoints;

       int size;

       float mapObstacleThreshold;

    }
```

In the above example, The base class "OccGridMapUtil" has 2 type params, but its derived class "OccGridMapUtilConfig" has only 1 type param. In its constructor, it passes "gridMap" to the constructor of "OccGridMapUtil". But according to the constructor of "OccGridMapUtil", how to determine the specific type of "ConcreteCacheMethod" ?

Comment: Would you understand what it was doing in a non-templated class?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth, I didnt explain clearly, now i updated my question

Comment: I don't understand the question.  In `OccGridMapUtil`, `ConcreteCacheMethod` *is* a specific type.  If it's being used as a base class of `OccGridMapUtilConfig`, that type happens to be `GridMapCacheMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class isn't a template, but an instance of that template.

More specifically, it is the instance `OccGridMapUtil<ConcreteOccGridMap, GridMapCacheMethod>`

The subclass is a template with parameter `ConcreteOccGridMap`, so that will be substituted when the subclass is instantiated, but the other type isn't part of the template,so it must exist at namespace scope as a valid complete type.